# Inserting a row into Kivy MDDataTable does not work

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivymd, raspberry-pi4

I am using [Kivy MDDataTables](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/datatables/index.html) in a Python3 App. During runtime i want to dynamically add and remove rows in the table. The documentation gives the following example

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton


class Example(MDApp):
    data_tables = None

    def build(self):
        layout = MDFloatLayout()  # root layout
        # Creating control buttons.
        button_box = MDBoxLayout(
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
            adaptive_size=True,
            padding="24dp",
            spacing="24dp",
        )

        for button_text in ["Add row", "Remove row"]:
            button_box.add_widget(
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text=button_text, on_release=self.on_button_press
                )
            )

        # Create a table.
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5},
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=False,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(40)),
                ("Column 2", dp(40)),
                ("Column 3", dp(40)),
            ],
            row_data=[("1", "1", "2", "3")],
        )
        # Adding a table and buttons to the toot layout.
        layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        layout.add_widget(button_box)

        return layout

    def on_button_press(self, instance_button: MDRaisedButton) -> None:
        '''Called when a control button is clicked.'''

        try:
            {
                "Add row": self.add_row,
                "Remove row": self.remove_row,
            }[instance_button.text]()
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def add_row(self) -> None:
        last_num_row = int(self.data_tables.row_data[-1][0])
        self.data_tables.add_row((str(last_num_row + 1), "1", "2", "3"))

    def remove_row(self) -> None:
        if len(self.data_tables.row_data) > 1:
            self.data_tables.remove_row(self.data_tables.row_data[-1])


Example().run()
```

On call of `self.data_tables.add_row()` the program crashes with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'add_row'
```

I executed the code on two different systems with the same error:

Notebook:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.7
- Kivy v2.0.0
- KivyMD 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5,2021-06-06
- Virtual Environment installed via Anaconda
- Packages installed via Anaconda

Raspberry Pi 400:

- Raspbian GNU/Linux 11
- Python 3.9.2
- Kivy v2.1.0
- KivyMD 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06
- Virtual Environment installed via venv
- Packages installed via pip3

As fix I directly add the data to the `self.data_tables.row_data`. But this crashed after a few inserts and deletes due to internal index errors.

Why does the MDDataTables object does not have the methode add_row() as written in the documentation? Do I have installed the wrong version of kivyMD?

Comment: Did you try with method [**`update_row_data`**](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.2/components/datatables/#kivymd.uix.datatables.MDDataTable.update_row_data) ?

Comment: There is no documented `add_row()` method in the documentation for version `0.104.2` of `KivyMD`. The documentation that you link to is for version `1.0.0.dev0`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: Thank you for pointing that out. I am going to update KivyMD to the lastest version.